# Netbeans: How do I switch between c and c++ compiler?

Tags: c, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2. When I set up a project I choose the option for c/c++ application.

However, when I compile my code it appears to be running a c++ compiler

```
(g++ -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF)
```

instead of a c compiler. When I go to "Project Properties" under "Build" I see I can set options for a "c compiler" "c++ compiler" and "FORTRAN Compiler".

However I don't see how I am supposed to select among these as to switch the code from compiling in c++ to compiling in c (with the settings specified on the "c compiler" tab") instead of c++.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have split your post to make it easier to read.  I also fixed a couple of English issues and I marked the command by preceding it with4 spaces.  It would also help to post a screenshot of you options screen.

Comment: Thanks. Since posting the question I have found that I can change the compiler to gcc by clicking the main file (main.cpp) and going into properties. However, I'm not sure if it really is trying to compile the code as c. I'm getting the following warning: "cc1plus: warning: command line option '-std=c99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++" the command line is "gcc    -c -g -std=c99 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o main.cpp" and certain c99 functions are giving errors.

Comment: my guess: remove `main.cpp` and add `main.c`, cf https://cnd.netbeans.org/cnd-tutorial.html#AddingNewFiles

Comment: @Christoph, that seems to be the issue, as discussed over at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561723/why-wont-gcc-std-c99-allow-me-to-use-vlas?noredirect=1#comment56867288_34561723. Thank you. I'll accept your response if you want to make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I could gather online, Netbeans selects the compiler by file type, not project.

So you need to remove your `main.cpp` and add a `main.c` instead (cf [Adding New Files](https://cnd.netbeans.org/cnd-tutorial.html#AddingNewFiles) from the tutorial).

Comment: Something must be not right, i did that change to all files, but the output compiling of netbeans is still g++