# Why won't "gcc-std=c99 ...." allow me to use VLAs?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

I am trying to compile the code below using

> gcc -c -g -std=c99 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o main.cpp

The code below uses VLA in the function func, which I believe should be supported by c99 which I believe I am using via the flag -std=c99.

The problem is when I run this I get the following warning and errors:

> cc1plus: warning: command line option '-std=c99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
>
> main.cpp:11:35: error: use of parameter outside function body before ']' token
>   void func(int a, int b, int arry[a][b]){
>                                      ^
>
> main.cpp:11:38: error: use of parameter outside function body before ']' token
>   void func(int a, int b, int arry[a][b]){

The first warning makes me question if gcc is trying to compile the code as c or c++. The second makes me think that there is a problem using the VLA features, although my understanding is that c99 should support that.

The code is:

```
void func(int a, int b, int arry[a][b]){
 //Do stuff
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int setSize=6;
    int sets[setSize][setSize]={0};

    func(setSize,setSize,sets);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you name the file `main.cpp` if it's not C++? Or is it?

Comment: The comment you delete from the post is very relevant to that -- that's the default in my IDE.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't compiler C code with a C++ compiler. The error messages are very clear.

Comment: The part deleted in the edit by @YuHao  is absolutely irrelevant. The removal was justified.

Comment: Olaf. I thought that gcc would compile c code (as opposed to g++). How is it clear from the error messages that I'm compiling c++ and not c? That's my question.

Comment: @ABD: Because "...but not for C++" makes it clear, as does the fact that the warning is produced by the program `cc1plus`, in addition to the fact that C++ doesn't allow VLAs at all.

Comment: Does gcc still compile .cpp files as C++, if you specify `-std=c99` (not a C++ standard), and if you use gcc instead of g++?

Comment: @Paul: Yes and I questioned that in the text of my question. Really I'm asking what's wrong with my gcc syntax? Doesn't gcc compile c?

Comment: @ABD: The behavior of gcc will vary depending on what you pass to it. By default, if you pass it a `.cpp` file, it'll compile it as C++, regardless of whether you invoke it as `gcc` or `g++`.

Comment: `gcc` is the Gnu Compiler *Collection* and can act as front-end for more than just C. If your file doesn't have the proper extension, pass `-xc` to force C mode

Comment: @Christoph, that seems to be the issue. Thank you. I'll accept your response if you want to make it an answer.

Comment: per this page: `https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html`, to select a standard for C++, the gcc parameter would be similar to: `-std=c++11` not `-std=c11`   You can adjust the `11` for the version of the standard you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc` is the Gnu Compiler *Collection* and can act as frontend for more that just C (though not using the language-specific shim might fail without passing additional options, if it works at all).

If your file doesn't have the correct extension, you may set the language explicitly via `-x`, eg `-xc` in your case.

However, the preferable option would be to fix the filename.